# image picker not dismissing when picture tapped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

when the bar button item is tapped the popover view shows fine but it does not dismiss when a photo is selected. Am I missing something? What should i do?

```
-(IBAction)addPhoto:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
    [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{   
    // Delete any existing image.
    NSManagedObject *oldImage = imageClass.image;
    if (oldImage != nil)
    {
        [imageClass.managedObjectContext deleteObject:oldImage];
    }

    // Create an image object for the new image.
    NSManagedObject *myImage = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Image" inManagedObjectContext:imageClass.managedObjectContext];
    imageClass.image = myImage;

    // Set the image for the image managed object.
    [image setValue:selectedImage forKey:@"image"];

    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are trying to dismiss the image picker controller but you need to dismiss the popover that it is in. Things need to be dismissed based on how they were presented.

Change:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

to:

```
[popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

Calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` would be used if you have called `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

Comment: Didn't work how? The popover stayed in view or something else? Verify if `popover` is `nil` or not inside the image picker delegate method when it's reached.

Comment: it stayed in view. Nothing changed

Comment: And what about the rest of my question? Have you verified the `popover` isn't `nil` at the time you try to call `dismissPopoverAnimated:`?

Comment: Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint at that line. When the breakpoint is reached, look at the value for `popover`.

Comment: Without seeing your latest code and knowing what you are actually doing, it's pretty hard to help any further. Did you change both image picker delegate methods?

Answer (score 1):

To dismiss UIPopoverViewController on the selection of a photo from gallery, you need to add following lines in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method after picking an image.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
     [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
     [imagePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not set `delegate` of `imagePicker` to self. Plus you need to take `popover` as instance variable to dismiss in delegate method.

Comment: When I try doing that I get this error:  
i get the error: /Users/Graham/Desktop/Interface/Interface/DetailViewController.m:79:24: Assigning to 'id<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'DetailViewController *const __strong' – user1858163

Comment: And I do have <imagepickerdelegate> in the header

Answer (score 0):

1) in you .h you must add `<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>`
2) add `imagePicker.delegate=self;` so your `addPhoto` method should look as below:

```
-(IBAction)addPhoto:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate=self;  //add this line to your code
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
           initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];

[popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender
                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: i get the error: /Users/Graham/Desktop/Interface/Interface/DetailViewController.m:79:24: Assigning to 'id<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'DetailViewController *const __strong'

Comment: In DetailViewController.h, interface declaration should look like @interface DetailViewController:UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

Comment: What about <uipopoverdelegate>?

Comment: keep it too. Make it @interface DetailViewController:UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIPopoverDelegate>

Answer (score 0):

just give the delegate `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` and `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` in `.h` file

Answer (score 0):

you must add UIImagePickerControllerDelegate to your corresponding .h file and also Check this Code

```
 -(IBAction)addPhoto:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender 
{
  UIImagePickerController *imagePicker3 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  imagePicker3.delegate = self;
  imagePicker3.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  imagePicker3.allowsEditing = YES;
  imagePicker3.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.image"]
  [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker3 animated:YES];

}
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info { 
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
_imageselected.image=[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still experiencing this infamous error when using UIImagePickerController:

```
Assigning to 'id <UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>' from   incompatible type 'DetailViewController *const __strong'
```

try to move

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
```

to the

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  //do your stuff
}
```

and don't forget to include the delegate protocol definitions (<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>) in the corresponding .h file.

This solved my problem, hope it's gonna help someone else. Don't know if its the best solution, but worked for me in a similar case.